# How can you fix color banding from VHS video tape in post-processing?

Tags: premiere, video-quality, davinci-resolve, virtualdub, vhs

Old VHS tapes often have horizontal lines/bands that slowly scroll up or down the video during playback. This video is already on DVD, so I am trying to remove the banding in post-processing.

The Tools I'm using include:
VirtualDub, AviSynth, Premiere Pro CC, Davinci Resolve.

Are there any techniques, plugins or scripts that can help remove this?

Comment: Those are usually "hum bars" caused by the difference in rate between NTSC video vertical (59.97) and US AC power (60.0). It would be a great trick indeed to build a plugin to find and track those. I've never heard of such a thing and would be surprised to find one -- but I'm always being amazed by what people accomplish. Good luck

Comment: "Bah Hum Bars!"

Answer (score 1):

[Neat Video](https://www.neatvideo.com/) has been working miracles on footage for us so far, you can give the trial a go! We've never tried it on this specific artifact (that I know of) but it does have features for restoration/archival type damage, and I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

If the video in question is in grayscale, you can always just remove the colour by **reducing the colour saturation by 100%**. You can do this in OBS by adding the Effect Filter "Color Correction" on the Video Capture Device.

Answer (score -1):

Caused by not enough back pressure on the tape as it goes to the head try cleaning the head if that doesn't work the machine needs to be checked by a tech.

dca productions

Comment: > *This video is already on DVD, so I am trying to remove the banding.* < so I don't think this will be useful to the OP. But I'd be interested if these types of pre-processing techniques are discussed elsewhere on Video.SE